# Is it possible to add mapping outside of index of elastic search?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

So I have following problem: currently python script parses logs and dynamically creates new index based on log filename (consists of datetime) and inserts there some data.

From what I understood, parameter passed in `bulk` function called `doc_type` does name this dynamically created mapping.

So here's the problem. I need to change this mapping to my, with `"type": "nested"` parameter and I'm stucked on how to properly create some-kind of a 'global' mapping so in dynamically created indexes I could also just pass `doc_type="my_mapping"` to `es.bulk` function and it won't create new but use my mapping type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updt: Figured it out. Elastic search has thing called `templates`.

So what I did was pretty simple.
First run this query at kibana dashboard:

```
put /_templates/my_template
{
  "template": "WILDCARD_FOR_INDICES",
  "mappings": {
      "my_mapping": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          }
      }
  }
}
}
```

And in python script I used `es.bulk` function with no `doc_type` argument, so bulk could use mapping from my template.